# How can we simplify the expression $P+\sqrt{P^2+\sqrt{P^4+\sqrt{ P^8+\cdots)}}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a way to reduce the expression
$P+\sqrt{P^2+\sqrt{P^4+\sqrt{ P^8+\cdots)}}}$?

Comment: What is $P$? Any real number, a real number from some specific interval, something else?

Comment: P is any real number....question was just to simplify the given expression..

Comment: Assuming existence / convergence, $P + \sqrt{P^2+\sqrt{P^4+\cdots}} = P(1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\cdots}}) = PS$, say.  Can you find $S$?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think $P$ is prime, however, primes are usually denoted with a $p$.

Comment: You may also need http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HerschfeldsConvergenceTheorem.html

Comment: @Aleksandar: No, $P$ doesn't have to be prime here.

Answer (score 26):

So our target expression is:

$$ P + \sqrt{P^2 + \sqrt{P^4...}}$$

An indirect approach that is quite simple is to consider

$$ P \left( 1 + \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 ...}} \right)$$

It follows that of we distribute the P we will have

$$ P +P \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1 ...}} $$

Which yields

$$ P + \sqrt{P^2 + P^2\sqrt{1 + ...}}$$

And again we can distribute under the next root for $P^4$ then $P^8$ etc...

So now the trick is to evaluate:

$$S = 1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{...}}$$

It follows that

$$(S-1)^2 = 1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{...}}$$

And therefore

$$ (S-1)^2 = S$$

Using this we can solve and find

$$S^2-3S + 1 = 0$$

Which has solutions given by the quadratic formula:

$$S = \frac{3 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$$

A simple test of evaluating the first few terms of

$$S = 1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{...}}$$

Suggests that solution closer to $2$ is in order this we have

$$S =  \frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$$

And this to evaluate:

$$ P + \sqrt{P^2 + P^2\sqrt{1 + ...}}$$

Is just

$$P \left(   \frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2}   \right)$$

Answer (score 3):

If the series converges to $S$ then $S= P + \sqrt{P^2+\sqrt{P^4+\cdots}} = P\left(1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\cdots}}\right) = PA$,

where $A$ is $1 + \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\cdots}}$.

Now, $(A-1)^{2}=A$ so

$A$= $\frac{3+\sqrt 5}{2}$ or $\frac{3-\sqrt 5}{2}$, but we discard the latter root, because if you look at the series $A$ it is obvious that $A>2$.

Therefore,  $S=\frac{3+\sqrt 5}{2}P$.